# How to get microphone input volume value with web audio api?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I am using the microphone input with web audio api and need to get the volume value.

Right now I have already got the microphone to work:
http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/09/Live-Web-Audio-Input-Enabled

Also, i know there's a method manipulating the volume of audio file:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webaudio/intro/

```
    // Create a gain node.
    var gainNode = context.createGain();
    // Connect the source to the gain node.
    source.connect(gainNode);
    // Connect the gain node to the destination.
    gainNode.connect(context.destination);
   // Reduce the volume.
   gainNode.gain.value = 0.5;
```

But how to combine these two and get the input volume value?
I just need to the value, no need to manipulate it.

Does anybody know?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are two main reasons to want to get the "volume":

1. detect *when the source "clips"* - i.e. the absolute value of the signal goes over a preset level, usually very near 1.0, where it will start clipping.
2. give the user a feel for *how loud their signal is*.

The reason I list these separately is because the first requires that you process *every* sample - because you might miss a short transient otherwise.  For this, you'll need to use a `ScriptProcessor` node, and you'll have to iterate through every sample in the buffer inside `onaudioprocess` to look for absolute values above your clip level.  You *could* just determine the RMS level then, too - just sum the squares of each sample, divide by N and take the square root.  **DO NOT** render from within `onaudioprocess`, though - set values that you access on `requestAnimationFrame`.

You can also use an `AnalyserNode` to do the level detection, and just average out the data, kind of like what the [other answer does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21247724/1175496)  with `getAverageVolume`.  However, the other answer is **NOT** a good use of `ScriptProcessor` - in fact, it's doing no processing of the script node at all, not even passing the data through, it's just using it like a timer callback.  You would be **FAR** better served by using `requestAnimationFrame` as the visual callback; don't ever set layout or visual parameters from inside `onaudioprocess` like this, or you're begging to thrash your audio system.  If you don't need clip detection, just do the `getByteFrequencyCount`/`getAverageVolume`from above on an `AnalyserNode` (but you should minimize the number of bands in the Analyser - 64 is the minimum, I think), and you should pre-allocate and reuse a `Uint8Array` rather than allocating it each time (that will amp up the garbage collection).

Comment: Is there any *fast* way to get peak level yet?  I would expect this to have been a basic feature of AnalyserNode (in addition to RMS).  It goes through all the trouble of FFT for us but doesn't give the basics needed for a simple peak or RMS meter.  Is ScriptProcessorNode still the fastest way?  If so, I'm afraid that it's just too slow to be usable for more than a few channels at a time.  Calling on your expertise and hoping for a miracle.  :-)

Comment: Nope, ScriptProcessor is currently it (for detecting peak clips).  AudioWorkers will make this faster, of course, but it's not shipping yet.

Comment: Why use `getByteFrequencyData` instead of `getByteTimeDomainData` ?

Answer (score 10):

Although it is a bit late, I still hope to help you.

[h5_get_microphone_volume](https://codepen.io/huooo/pen/xJNPOL)

```
var audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)()
var mediaStreamSource = null
var meter = null

if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then((stream) => {
    mediaStreamSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(stream)
    meter = createAudioMeter(audioContext)
    mediaStreamSource.connect(meter)
  })
}

function createAudioMeter(audioContext, clipLevel, averaging, clipLag) {
  const processor = audioContext.createScriptProcessor(512)
  processor.onaudioprocess = volumeAudioProcess
  processor.clipping = false
  processor.lastClip = 0
  processor.volume = 0
  processor.clipLevel = clipLevel || 0.98
  processor.averaging = averaging || 0.95
  processor.clipLag = clipLag || 750

  // this will have no effect, since we don't copy the input to the output,
  // but works around a current Chrome bug.
  processor.connect(audioContext.destination)

  processor.checkClipping = function () {
    if (!this.clipping) {
      return false
    }
    if ((this.lastClip + this.clipLag) < window.performance.now()) {
      this.clipping = false
    }
    return this.clipping
  }

  processor.shutdown = function () {
    this.disconnect()
    this.onaudioprocess = null
  }

  return processor
}

function volumeAudioProcess(event) {
  const buf = event.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0)
  const bufLength = buf.length
  let sum = 0
  let x

  // Do a root-mean-square on the samples: sum up the squares...
  for (var i = 0; i < bufLength; i++) {
    x = buf[i]
    if (Math.abs(x) >= this.clipLevel) {
      this.clipping = true
      this.lastClip = window.performance.now()
    }
    sum += x * x
  }

  // ... then take the square root of the sum.
  const rms = Math.sqrt(sum / bufLength)

  // Now smooth this out with the averaging factor applied
  // to the previous sample - take the max here because we
  // want "fast attack, slow release."
  this.volume = Math.max(rms, this.volume * this.averaging)
  document.getElementById('audio-value').innerHTML = this.volume
}
```

Comment: What is the units of this.volume? dbs? percent of something?

Comment: I upvoted but the above code is by Chris Wilson @cwilso. See: https://github.com/cwilso/volume-meter

Answer (score 9):

I did a volume display for a playing audio when I was studying HTML 5.

I followed this great tutorial

http://www.smartjava.org/content/exploring-html5-web-audio-visualizing-sound

```
 // setup a analyzer
 analyser = context.createAnalyser();
 analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.3;
 analyser.fftSize = 1024;

 javascriptNode = context.createScriptProcessor(2048, 1, 1);


 javascriptNode.onaudioprocess = function() {

        // get the average, bincount is fftsize / 2
        var array =  new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
        analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
        var average = getAverageVolume(array)

         console.log('VOLUME:' + average); //here's the volume
 }

 function getAverageVolume(array) {
        var values = 0;
        var average;

        var length = array.length;

        // get all the frequency amplitudes
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            values += array[i];
        }

        average = values / length;
        return average;
  }
```

**NOTE**: I just don't know if it will work on an audio input came from a microphone

Comment: Tutorial link is dead, but I have found this (maybe it's the same article): https://dzone.com/articles/exploring-html5-web-audio


This tutorial is a great place to start learning Web Audio API, but it uses deprecated features (like javascriptNode).
I suggest to read it once and then learn the new AudioWorklet feature: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702721/how-to-get-microphone-volume-using-audioworklet