# Single Equalizer Progress bar with Javascript, HTML

Tags: javascript, html

At first look at my image which I am uploaded. [image: mic frequency catch Bar]

I want to do this with HTML and JS. I am trying in many ways, but don't do this.
when my mic value is increased my progress bar also increase with the different color. like my uploaded image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get microphone input volume value with web audio api?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21247571/how-to-get-microphone-input-volume-value-with-web-audio-api)

Comment: no, i don't need to get microphone data, i need only UI design.

Comment: Then don't state "when my mic value is increased my progress bar also increase" in your question ;) An idea would be to use an image of the whole progress bar and crop it horizontally to just the part that should be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite an answer to your problem but your job to do the analogy. 
First, see bootstrap progress bar  and how to manipulate it here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp

Now, you can connect it to your case to do so [go here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia)

Comment: ok. but i want to design my progress bar like this.. in every progress bar have only one color.. but there are in 3-4 color with vertical view.
how can i do this. :(